# Does Linux support setting XDP programs on the egress path?

Tags: linux, ebpf, xdp-bpf

Does Linux support setting XDP programs on the egress path ?

I found this [patch](https://lwn.net/Articles/818591/), but I don't know if it was accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as of kernel v6.3, this feature is not supported. The patch you are linking was indeed never accepted into upstream. Though I believe there is no public record of why or if the original author plans on submitting a modified version in future.

Comment: The mailing list discussion is [available here](https://lore.kernel.org/all/20200123014210.38412-12-dsahern@kernel.org/t/#mf08f872fef38076fd0497f6ce1e1d74ce6f4bb4f) - There was some push back because the advantage of egress XDP other existing egress hooks was unclear, but it meant more XDP work for driver maintainers, and the discussion about XDP queuing would likely have to happen first anyway (I'm probably taking a few shortcuts in my summary, but go read the thread if you feel like it). I don't remember of a clear consensus though so not sure if a future version may still come.